# Zend Framework 2 - Multiple instances of the same service

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a service that reads from a db, accepting a parameter for a SQL query, and i need to call it for different values of the parameter, but in the same view. Actually, this results in calling it with the last value all the times.
Example (this is in my controller):

```
public function someAction () {
        return new ViewModel(array (
            "welcome" => $this->homeService->findText("welcome"),
            "address" => $this->homeService->findText("address"),
            "map" => $this->homeService->findText("map"),
    ));
}
```

Doing this calls my homeService as its parameter was "map" all the times.

I tried to set this in my module.config.php (Site\Service\HomeServiceInterface is my homeService of course):

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Site\Service\HomeServiceInterface' => 'Site\Factory\HomeServiceFactory',
    ),
    'shared' => array (
        'Site\Service\HomeServiceInterface' => false
    ),
),
```

since i read that 'shared' array should allow to have multiple instances of the same service, but this didn't work. So, besides creating another service (which i'd find horrible) i can't imagine how to do it. Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**

HomeService (the interface has everything needed)

```
use Site\Model\Home;
use Site\Model\HomeInterface;
use Site\Mapper\TextMapperInterface;


class HomeService implements HomeServiceInterface {
    protected $textMapper;

    public function __construct (TextMapperInterface $textMapper) {
        $this->textMapper = $textMapper;
    }
    public function findText($name) {
        return $this->textMapper->find($name);
    }
}
```

TextMapper is as follows:

```
use Site\Model\HomeInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

class TextMapper implements TextMapperInterface {
    protected $homePrototype;
    protected $adapter;
    protected $hydrator;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter, HomeInterface $homePrototype, HydratorInterface $hydrator) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->homePrototype = $homePrototype;
        $this->hydrator = $hydrator;
    }

    public function find($name) {
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from("mono");
        $select->where(array("name = ?" => $name));
        $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult() && $result->getAffectedRows()) {
            return $this->hydrator->hydrate($result->current(), $this->homePrototype);
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("{$name} doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

HomeInterface is the model, which has simply getter and setter methods.

Comment: Please show us how an implementation of `HomeServiceInterface` looks like and especially how does `findText` method looks like.

Comment: @awons I added the HomeServiceInterface, as well as the mapper it instantiates

Answer (score 0):

Well, i suppose i solved, so i'll post my idea, which is surely working fine.
Of course, textMapper gets instantiated by the `__construct ()` only once, so i suppose it happens the same way everytime it's called in the same action. I decided to modify everything. I had a db with 3 rows: `id`, `name` (which i was using until now in my `find($name)` function) and `text`.
My model looked this way:

```
class Home implements HomeInterface {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $text;


    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText ($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}
```

Now i changed the table: fields are `id`, `home`, `certification`, `about`, `welcome`, `address`, `map` (the last 3 being the ones i need in this case). So now my new `Home` has new getters and setters to fit this new way. (`getHome()`, `setHome($home)`, etc...)
Mapper's `find()` doesn't need a `$name` argument anymore. Now i can use the getter i need when i'm in the view, to show the text i want. My action now is simply:

```
public function someAction () {
    return new ViewModel(array (
        "welcome" => $this->homeService->findText("welcome"),
    ));
}
```

and in the some.phtml page:

```
<?php echo $this->welcome->getWelcome(); ?>
<?php echo $this->welcome->getAddress(); ?>
<?php echo $this->welcome->getMap(); ?>
```

I suppose this is a better design than it was before.